# HTML Email : Outlook puts down the text after space

Tags: outlook, html-email

I am making HTML Emailer.

The issue i am facing is that , when i see the output of my code in Outlook, then

*Register Online* text gets down in the outlook.

like **Register** in one line and **Online** in new line.

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style=";border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background: transparent;">
                 <tbody><tr>
                  <td valign="middle" height="40" align="center" class="main-bg-color" style=" background: #ffee00;color: black;display: block;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px;!important; width:100px; cursor: pointer;">
                   <div class="modtxt"><span class="wrap_textbox"><a style="color: black;text-align: center; display:block; text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;font-size: 10px;line-height: 40px;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: \'proxima_novasemibold\', Arial, sans-serif;" href="http://www.hubilo.com/widget/webpanel/login.php?event=c1d1b1dc8d40c37429a8fd1f627c5c5e"><span style="font-weight:100;">Register Online</span></a></span></div>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                 </tbody></table>
```

How can I solve it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but if it's make sure that "register online" doesn't ever break onto two lines, then the easy solution for Outlook is to use a non-breaking space character (`&nbsp;`) rather than a space.

```
REGISTER&nbsp;ONLINE
```

This should solve that particular issue.

Comment: This will work in EVERY email client, not just Outlook. It is a very good universal solution.